# How can I set up my dev environment for MySQL Data on one dev machine in order to develop two different apps that start from the same source database?

Tags: mysql, development-environment

I have a LAMP development stack with MySQL 8 database, on my local dev machine.  There is a fairly large database, with over 10 databases each database having 5-10 tables each, so there are roughly 100 or more tables sprinkled throughout the code with various complex SQL queries.

I need to create a *duplicate* version of the app I am developing to be hosted on a completely separate server with its own database and code.  `App1` will be on one server, `App2` will be hosted on another server.  Each will have their own separate codebase and data, where data will be greatly modified on `App2`, even though the initial data for `App2` will be identical to that of `App1`.

For example, `database.table` will start up to be the same on both, but later `App1` will have one set of fields, and `App2` will start having a different set of fields.  And so on for about a hundred of other tables.

Note:  the actual data rows & values will change greatly but actual schema changes to the database structure and database fields will be small and mostly non-existent (left as-is), but the need to have two separate databases is essential.

My problem is this - how do I develop both apps on my local dev machine while having two apps with different data needs that start out with the same database names?  MySQL does not have a concept of schema or namespace, so I cannot simply copy the database tables into another namespace, and reuse the table names that way.

One rough solution could be to copy over the database but add a prefix, like `app2_database.table`.  I feel it is a wonky solution, since it will pollute the namespace so to speak, with duplicate database tables on my dev.  I want to ask if there is a better solution available to address my concern.

What can I do to be able to develop both apps concurrently using one dev machine, where apps come with different data needs but start off with the same collection databases (I am using MySQL `database` meaning here). My goal is to be able to develop both apps concurrently (i.e. one one day, the other another day), on same machine.

Comment: You can (and imho really should) setup two independent instances of mysql server on the same machine, one for each app. Trying to serve (seemingly) two versions of a schema in one database will set you in hell's kitchen ... If the apps are independent enough to run on different machines in production, they are independent enough to run on different database instances in development.

Comment: Thank you, I followed your advice and I think it is quite an amicable solution, and I am going to use it going forward.  Feel free to make your comment an answer, if you like.